# Python - Turning text links to html

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
def linkify(msg):
    for m in msg.split(" "):
        m = m.lower()
        if m.startswith("https:") or m.startswith("http:"):
            msg = re.sub(m, f"<a href='{m}' target='_blank'>{m}</a>", msg, re.I)
    return msg
```

What I'm trying to do is make plain links into html links. While ignoring already html links the user may or may not sent. I'm using this test string: `hi how are you https://google.com/img https://google.com/img/l <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> hi <a href='http://test.com/img' target='_blank'>http://test.com/img</a> <a href='https://test.com/hi/lol' target='_blank'>https://test.com/hi/lol</a>`

**Output**

```
hi how are you <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a>/l <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> hi <a href='http://test.com/img' target='_blank'>http://test.com/img</a> <a href='https://test.com/hi/lol' target='_blank'>https://test.com/hi/lol</a>
```

Notice the link: `<a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a>/l`
the `/1` gets completely ignored and I don't know why

**Desired Output**

```
 <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> <a href='https://google.com/img/1' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img/1</a> <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> hi <a href='http://test.com/img' target='_blank'>http://test.com/img</a> <a href='https://test.com/hi/lol' target='_blank'>https://test.com/hi/lol</a>
```

Comment: what is your desired output please?

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: ```https://google.com/img https://google.com/img/l``` those two links into anchor tags without disturbing the already anchored tags keep in mind that links are not always known

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import regex as re

text = """hi how are you https://google.com/img https://google.com/img/l <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> hi <a href='http://test.com/img' target='_blank'>http://test.com/img</a> <a href='https://test.com/hi/lol' target='_blank'>https://test.com/hi/lol</a>"""

rx = re.compile(r'<a.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://\S+')
text = rx.sub(lambda m: f"<a href='{m.group(0)}' target='_blank'>{m.group(0)}</a>", text)

print(text)
```

Which yields

```
hi how are you <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> <a href='https://google.com/img/l' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img/l</a> <a href='https://google.com/img' target='_blank'>https://google.com/img</a> hi <a href='http://test.com/img' target='_blank'>http://test.com/img</a> <a href='https://test.com/hi/lol' target='_blank'>https://test.com/hi/lol</a>
```

See [**a demo for the expression**](https://regex101.com/r/zqvSWk/1) on regex101.com.